# With a focus on erasing the value filled in the OTP box in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I' am using TextFormField to create OTP box.
how to archive this output without dependencies to otp character number erase to focusing previous box to one by one foucus previous box.